# Deploying GWT app with own external library

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have a GWT project [com.bob.gwt] that uses another library of my own, [com.bob.domain], which is used by both in the client and server. The domain project is exposed via gwt.xml project in com.bob.gwt.

When the server runs, it indicates that some Server classes from com.bob.domain could not be found in the web app, but were found on the class path and added. The WAR directory doesn't have the .java or .class files from com.bob.domain.

The com.bob.domain is added as a library in the Java Bulid Path Window's Projects tab, and also checked on the Order and Export tab in Eclipse. Do I have to set com.bob.domain as a jar and import that jar in com.bob.gwt? Can I just include the domain source in my gwt project so I can debug all at once without having to manually build a jar, and have everything in my WAR folder ready to go for deployment?

Answer (score 3):

During development, it's convenient to use Eclipse's project reference mechanism instead of rebuilding "domain.jar" every time. In that case, it's safe to ignore GWT's warning.

When you perform the "real builds" outside of Eclipse (which I would strongly recommend), you usually can't make use of Eclipse's project reference <sup>(except maybe if you're using [Ant4Eclipse](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/node/6))</sup>, so you'll need to tell the GWT compiler (gwtc), and the server side compiler (javac), where to find everything they need, including the domain project's files.

Then, for deployment, you'll need to put "domain.jar" into the "WEB-INF/lib" of your war.

Comment: when doing a GWT compile though, it's not clear to me how to specify where the JAR is. It sounds like though for the real build, I can just export my domain project to a jar and drop it in the WEB-INF/lib folder as you mentioned on your last line.

Comment: How the JAR/sources etc are specified, depends on how you build. e.g. with ant, you'd add a `<pathelement location="..."/>` to your `<classpath>`.